# WP API Response does not show my registered metadata

Tags: custom-post-types, post-meta, rest-api

I am trying to get metadata from a custom post type `splash_location` however it's not showing up in my response. I have registered my metatag `splash_location_title` but it doesn't show up in my JSON request.

```
function splash_location_custom_post_type() {
  register_post_type('splash_location',
    array(
      'labels'      => array(
        'name'          => __('Locations', 'textdomain'),
        'singular_name' => __('Location', 'textdomain'),
      ),
      'supports' => array( 'title', 'custom-fields' ),
      'menu_icon'   => 'dashicons-admin-page',
      'public'      => true,
      'has_archive' => true,
      'show_in_rest' => true,
     )
  );
}
add_action('init', 'splash_location_custom_post_type');

$meta_args = array( 
    'type'         => 'string',
    'description'  => 'A meta key associated with a string meta value.',
    'single'       => true,
    'show_in_rest' => true,
);
register_meta( 'splash_location', 'splash_location_title', $meta_args );



//Code in my block file to get splash_location data   
const getLocationPosts = () => axios
    .get('/wp-json/wp/v2/splash_location/')
    .then(response => {
        const { data } = response
        console.log(data)
    })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For posts (Posts, Pages and custom post types), the very first parameter for [`register_meta()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_meta/) is always `post` and to set a custom post type, use the `object_subtype` argument in the third parameter like so:

```php
$meta_args = array(
    'object_subtype' => 'splash_location', // the post type
    'type'           => 'string',
    'description'    => 'A meta key associated with a string meta value.',
    'single'         => true,
    'show_in_rest'   => true,
);
register_meta( 'post', 'splash_location_title', $meta_args );
```

Or you could instead use [`register_post_meta()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_post_meta/) which accepts the post type as the first parameter:

```php
$meta_args = array(
    'type'         => 'string',
    'description'  => 'A meta key associated with a string meta value.',
    'single'       => true,
    'show_in_rest' => true,
);
register_post_meta( 'splash_location', 'splash_location_title', $meta_args );
```

So in your existing code, you'd simply replace the `register_meta` with `register_post_meta`..

Comment: Amazing! That worked